# Outlook Graph email API: Threaded Email Conversations

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-restapi, outlook-graph-api

I have an application that I have to integrate with the outlook via Graph API. I need to retrieve the conversations which I am getting using the Graph Mail API. But the graph API is not able to return the object of the email in the form of threads(like that of a conversation thread between two email ids). Also, there is no field in the object that can specify to which thread a particular email belongs so that I can group them in my app.

Is there any way I can achieve the same.

Comment: You may want to get started from this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/conversationthread?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think there is some severe lack of documentation on this everyday use case.

The solution it seems is to filter your messages by the `conversationId`.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63570384/2591194.